# matlab - minimum euclidian distances between unique pais of points of two structures

Tags: matlab, unique, distance

I have this distance matrix between 6 points of one structure and 5 points of the second structure:

```
a = [2.565  0.394   2.927   2.774   1.600;
    0.402   1.950   3.272   2.086   0.985;
    2.965   3.250   1.720   0.841   2.305;
    2.797   2.050   0.830   0.829   1.585;
    3.865   2.662   1.246   2.086   2.634;
    1.592   0.977   2.305   1.579   0.274]
```

I need the minimum distances between points. Sometimes I get one point between two points of the other structure. `0.274 0.394 0.402 0.830 0.829`
This means I will get point 4 (from the 6 points structure) to be closest to points 3 and 4 from the other structure. I am not allowed to have one point closest to two others.
How do I get unique pairs of these close points?
I think I should verify if there is a small difference between first 2 minima in a row. The problematic point is always in the middle of other two.
I need to get `0.274 0.394 0.402 0.830 0.841` (see answer 1).
My original code was:

```
for i = 1 : 6
    mins(i) = min(a(i, :));
end
mins = sort(mins);
mins = mins(1 : 5);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You tagged the question with Matlab but there is no Matlab code. Can you elaborate how this question is related to Matlab?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You probably need to explain it better. Also, how can that be a distance matrix when it is not symmetric and the diagonal is not zero?

Comment: @LuisMendo It is the distance matrix between 6 and 5 points of two structures. Should I give the xyz coordinates of the structures?

Comment: Ah, I got it wrong, sorry. Now I see what the matrix means. Still, I think it can be confusing to readers. You should clarify that part, as well as the rest of the question, so you can get help

Comment: I don't have access to MATLAB 2019a, but [`matchpairs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matchpairs.html) looks promising. And I'm really curious for someone to try it. :D

Comment: @beaker It seems to work, I'll post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks beaker, I do hope the question gets another answer,

```
[pairs,a1,a2]=matchpairs(a,1,'min')
pairs =
     2     1
     1     2
     4     3
     3     4
     6     5
a1 =
     5
a2 =
  0×1 empty double column vector
```

Also I hope someone explains what the other outputs mean and when can they be useful.

Comment: `a1` and `a2` are the unmatched rows and columns, respectively. So no minimum was used from row 5, but all 5 columns were matched, which makes sense if you have 1 more row than columns. Thanks for trying it out! :)